# website animations not working and alignment is off

Tags: css, html, web, alignment

I have altered a template to quickly have an online resume my my job hunting. Everything looks great in Dreamweaver, but when I uploaded everything to my namecheap public_html folder something went wrong.I have no idea what the problem is, but I really need so help since I am trying to direct potential employers to this site. Here are all of the files i use in the index file and are uploaded in my file manager.

[Source File Folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wda077bur5seizo/AADstsYdsa8Rbh9hIt8T4ty4a?dl=0)

Comment: I would recommend putting the code directly in the question, instead of relying upon the trust of others to click your Dropbox link.

Comment: and what do you think looks wrong? also you can't view the code from that link, it says to download it. I won't do that, sorry.

Comment: Where can I display the source files so that they dont take so much space on a post like this? I think there are 11 files in total.